# Type acceptance in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the following typescript instructions:

```js
type Foo = string | number
    
function f<T extends string>(v : T) {
  (...)
}
    
const v : Foo = "ok"
    
f(v)
```

The checker has no problem with it, because I assume that even if `v` is a `Foo` (and could be a `number`), in this case, it's a **string** that is passed to `f` so it's OK.

But I don't understand technically how that works, because `f` only accepts a string (or extending), but we give it something typed as a `Foo`.

Comment: It's a `const` and you explicitly assigned a string to it - TS can safely narrow it to a string *in this case*. If it's *actually* a `Foo`, then it's not accepted: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBnYAnAlgOwOZQA+UOArgLYBGEGAUFA1LQGak4DGwWcOUzAPABUoEAB7AIOACao0mXHgB8ACgBuUAFxRBASigBvelAD0x5QDpLO2gF8jDWlIjsANgEMM0dj3RR1W+DgAbnsmZjUdIA)

Comment: You can also use `let`. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nrn91N). TS track mutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript performs [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to automatically *narrow* the apparent type of a value to a subtype in certain situations.  Narrowing via control flow analysis is a *very useful* feature of TypeScript, since otherwise you would need to explicitly and manually downcast or [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that a value of a certain type is a actually a value of a subtype.

Maybe you are already familiar with *type guards* such as what happens when you [check a variable with `typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards).  So if you write

```
function g(v: Foo) {
  if (typeof v === "string") {
    f(v); // compiles with no error
  }
}
```

then the compiler is happy because `v` has been narrowed from `Foo` to just `string`.  Without such analysis, you'd need to write `f(v as string)` even after knowing for sure that `v` is a `string`... and that would open yourself up to problems if you later edit the check to `typeof v === "number"`.

The code you have written also undergoes narrowing via control flow analysis:

---

If you have a variable of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (such as `v` of type `Foo`, which is really the union `string | number`), then the type checker will narrow the apparent type of this variable when you [assign](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) a value to the variable to just those union members appropriate for the assigned value.

So, the assignment `const v: Foo = "ok"` causes the compiler to narrow `v` from `string | number` to just `string`, because `"ok"` is assignable to `string` and not to `number`.  From that point onward in your program, the compiler treats `v` as being of type `string`, which allows you to call `f(v)` with no error.

Again, without such analysis, you'd have to write `f(v as string)`, which would be redundant and become a source for potential bugs if you edited to `const v: Foo = 123`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBnYAnAlgOwOZQA+UOArgLYBGEGAULQGak4DGwWcOUDAPACpQIAD2AQcAE1RpMuPAD4AFADcAXFD4BKKAG9aUKAHoDCgHRmNtAL70mrdpyh5la+HC279WBlAWhIcbyVkJBQAInRsfFD3PX1uZQ0AbkMDKABDABtURDgAazSQWOtrWhZOdChVWARkKFC80JsEoA)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to understand, didn't know that type narrowing also concerns function parameters. Gonna read the doc more deeply now :)